# Why do I keep getting a syntax error in BigQuery

Tags: sql, mysql, google-bigquery, syntax-error, operators

I can't seem to identify what I'm doing wrong. This is the error I'm getting

> No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING,
> INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY at [15:8]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oK5MR.png)

```
SELECT
  station_id,
  name,
  number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      start_station_id,
      COUNT(*) number_of_rides
    FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
    GROUP BY 
      start_station_id
  ) subquery
  INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations 
    ON station_id = subquery.start_station_id
ORDER BY
  number_of_rides DESC
```

Comment: That's not a syntax error... Seems like your tables have inconsistent data types. There's only one `=`. Which data type(s) have station_id and subquery.start_station_id?

Comment: Please take a moment to learn Markdown before posting here - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The message "No matching signature for operator = for argument types: STRING, INT64. Supported signature: ANY = ANY" suggests that the station_id and start_station_id columns have different data types, one being a string and the other being an integer.

To fix this cast one of the columns to the data type of the other column. You will need to figure which one is integer and which is string. e.g.

```
SELECT data_type
FROM `bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS`
WHERE table_name = 'citibike_stations' AND column_name = 'station_id'
```

I suggest converting the integer column to string (all integer can be strings, but not vice-versa)

```
SELECT
       station_id
     , name
     , number_of_rides AS number_of_rides_starting_at_station
FROM (
  SELECT start_station_id, COUNT(*) number_of_rides
  FROM bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_trips
  GROUP BY start_station_id
) subquery
INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
    ON CAST(station_id AS STRING) = subquery.start_station_id
ORDER BY number_of_rides DESC
```

Of course that's a guess, it may be the other way around i.e.:

```
INNER JOIN bigquery-public-data.new_york_citibike.citibike_stations
    ON station_id = CAST(subquery.start_station_id AS STRING)
```

nb: you could use safe_cast() for the conversion but should not need it for integer to string

Comment: Thank you! The second one worked. Much appreciated